# Retrieve checkbox state for certain users

Tags: php, sql, checkbox, foreach

I currently have some issues with how to solve this:

I have 2 tables: users and user_project. For each project (another table) users responsible for a project are stored in the user_project table.

Now I know how to format the inputted data, and store everything in the tables, but I'm stuck on editing a project. I'm stuck on how to check for each user wether they are linked to the project or not.

I should get a list like this:

```
user 1: [ ]
user 2: [ ]
user 3: [x]
user 4: [ ]
user 5: [x]
user 6: [ ]
```

This is what i have so for to get at least the users responsible:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users`");

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

            $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `user_project` WHERE `uid` = '". $row['id'] ."' AND `pid` = '". $pid ."'");

            while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql2)) {

                if ($row['id'] == $row2['uid']) {

                    echo '<input name="assignee[]" type="checkbox" value="'. $row['id'] .'" checked="checked"><span class="smaller">'. $row['email'] .'</span><br>';

                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: You should use a single query with a JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users`");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

        $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM `user_project` WHERE `uid` = '". $row['id'] ."' AND `pid` = '". $pid ."'");

        $row2 = mysql_fetch($sql2);

        // Is the user assigned? 

        if (($row2 !== false) && ($row2[0] > 0)) {
           // Yes he is
          echo '<input name="assignee[]" type="checkbox" value="'. $row['id'] .'" checked="checked"><span class="smaller">'. $row['email'] .'</span><br>';
        }

        else { 
           // No he is not 
           echo '<input name="assignee[]" type="checkbox" value="'. $row['id'] .'"><span class="smaller">'. $row['email'] .'</span><br>';
        }


    }
```

For each user you select the number of assignments. This should either be 0 or 1. There are more elegant solutions (like using join as suggested by @gontrollez), but this should do the trick and is only a slight variation of what you came up with